# How to add a repository correctly and use it in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I generated a gateway app with jhipster and generated a jparepository but when I try to use this repository I am getting the following error:

```
Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.nosi.gateway.service.ReceiptService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

This is how I use it in my service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReceiptService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiptService.class);

    private final ReceiptRepository receiptRepository;
    private final ReceiptRepositoryJpa receiptRepositoryJpa;
    private final ReceiptMapper receiptMapper;



    public ReceiptService(ReceiptRepository receiptRepository, ReceiptRepositoryJpa receiptRepositoryJpa, ReceiptMapper receiptMapper) {
        this.receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        this.receiptRepositoryJpa = receiptRepositoryJpa;
        this.receiptMapper = receiptMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Mono<ReceiptDTO> save(ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);
        return receiptRepository.save(receiptMapper.toEntity(receiptDTO)).map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Partially update a receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the entity to update partially.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Mono<ReceiptDTO> partialUpdate(ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to partially update Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);

        return receiptRepository
            .findById(receiptDTO.getId())
            .map(existingReceipt -> {
                receiptMapper.partialUpdate(existingReceipt, receiptDTO);

                return existingReceipt;
            })
            .flatMap(receiptRepository::save)
            .map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }


    public Flux<ReceiptDTO> findByCompany(Long companyUserID) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts by a company");
        return receiptRepository.findReceiptsByCompanyId(companyUserID).map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    public List<ReceiptDTO> findByCompanyJpa(Long companyUserID) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts by a company");
        return receiptRepositoryJpa.findReceiptsByCompanyId(companyUserID).stream().map(receiptMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ReceiptResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiptResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "receipt";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final ReceiptService receiptService;

    private final ReceiptRepository receiptRepository;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public ReceiptResource(ReceiptService receiptService, ReceiptRepository receiptRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.receiptService = receiptService;
        this.receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /receipts} : Create a new receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the receiptDTO to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new receiptDTO, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the receipt has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */

    @PostMapping("/receipts")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<ReceiptDTO>> createReceipt(@RequestBody ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);
        if (receiptDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new receipt cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        return receiptService
            .save(receiptDTO)
            .map(result -> {
                try {
                    return ResponseEntity
                        .created(new URI("/api/receipts/" + result.getId()))
                        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
                        .body(result);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
    }

    @GetMapping("/receipts/byUserId")
    public Mono<List<ReceiptDTO>> getAllReceiptsByCompanyId(@RequestParam Long companyId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Receipts");

        return receiptService.findByCompany(companyId).collectList();
    }

    @GetMapping("/receipts/byUserId")
    public List<ReceiptDTO> getAllReceiptsByCompanyIdJpa(@RequestParam Long companyId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Receipts");

        return receiptService.findByCompanyJpa(companyId);
    }
```

Repository

```
public interface ReceiptRepositoryJpa extends JpaRepository<Receipt, Long>  {

    List<Receipt> findReceiptsByCompanyId(Long id);

}
```

I also added this to my mainApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.nosi.gateway.repository.jpa")
public class NosiApp {

SOme methods are here generated by jhipster
}
```

Can someone give me a pointer how to fix this? I tried to use autowired in service and annotate my repository with @repository but still the same error.

ADDED POM

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Also I have this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you share also your pom.xml file?

Comment: Yes do you need only the dependency part or everything? Because it is generated by jhipster so its a bit long

Comment: I need to hibarnate dependency

Comment: I added the pom file

Comment: From hibernate onwards 5.2.0. hibernate-entitymanager is no longer needed. Hibernate-core 5.2.0 have problem with Spring Data JPA while process collection.Hibernate-core 5.2.1 and above is ok with Spring Data JPA if you are using Spring Data JPA.  Would you look at your version?

Comment: I could only find this: <hibernate.version>5.4.32.Final</hibernate.version> this is used in the jpamodelgen dependency. The version for core is not written do I have to add it manually?

Comment: try to it. but update question add application properties file as well.

Comment: I have a application properties class do you mean that?

Comment: Updating my hibernate core did not help me sadly, I used the latest version or hibernate core

Comment: I mean in resources folder location path

Comment: In jhipster there is no application.properties like in spring boot initilzr project. There is application.dev.yml I can post that? What do you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250624/discussion-between-anar-mmmdov-and-natyus).